# Uso de várias classes numa só declaração de CSS

Tags: css

Estou aprendendo um pouco sobre CSS e cheguei a uma dúvida, assim

```css
.header .menu .style-fonte {}
```

Porque tem os 3 nomes de uma classe `header` `menu` e `style-fonte`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso significa que o estilo será aplicado a um elemento que tenha a classe "style-fonte" e que esteja dentro de um elemento com a classe "menu" e que por sua vez esteja dentro de outro elemento, finalmente com a classe "header ".

Exemplo:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="style-fonte">
      Estilo se aplica a este elemento!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note que não é necessário que sejam filhos diretos uns dos outros, poderiam ser filhos indiretos.

Comment: Então isso quer dizer aonde sera aplicado a classe?

Comment: Criei um exemplo de onde a classe poderia ser aplicada.

Comment: Melhor, isso serve exatamente pra que ?

Comment: Pode colocar todo o caminho ou não... depende dos elemento que quer selecionar. Se você criar uma classe CSS `style-fonte` sem indicar o caminho então todos os elementos com a classe terão o estilo, se colocar um caminho, então nem todos terão o estilo, apenas os que estiverem no caminho.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O seu CSS não tem nenhum conteúdo, então essa regra não faz nada. Mas suponhamos que um conteúdo qualquer seja adicionado:

```
.header .menu .style-fonte {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

A primeira parte da regra - os **seletores** - dizem onde o estilo será aplicado. No caso, a todo elemento [de qualquer tipo] que possua a classe `style-fonte`, que seja descendente de um elemento com a classe `menu`, que por sua vez seja descendente de um elemento com a classe `header`. A [resposta do Miguel Angelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11355/215) dá um exemplo de estrutura que satisfaça a esse critério, mas poderia ser outra. A segunda parte da regra, a que está dentro das chaves, corresponde ao estilo que será aplicado nos elementos selecionados (no caso, fazer a cor de fundo ficar azul).

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h48rX/).

Comment: <style> 
.menu .logo .josimara { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #F00;}
.nome .teste .josimara { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #030;}
</style> 

<div class="menu"> <div class="logo"> <div class="josimara"></div> </div> </div>
<div class="nome"> <div class="teste"> <div class="josimara"></div> </div> </div>

Comment: Estou correta ao uso disso então?

Comment: @Josimara Sim, está. Veja seu exemplo em funcionamento: http://jsfiddle.net/h48rX/1/

Comment: Muito obrigado!